# Center hole in a helical coil spring - formula for tightening during extension?

Tags: classical-mechanics, spring, geometry, elasticity

A helical coil spring can be thought of a wire wrapped multiple times around a virtual cylinder. While extending the spring, the virtual cylinder becomes smaller, until at last the spring is as long as the constituting wire, and the virtual cylinder has zero diameter.

Is there a formula for the diameter of this cylinder as a function of extension? How does the position of the ends of the helical coil spring feature into this (along the circumference of the cylinder)? Are there any other variables that play into this (cross section of the wire, elastic properties of the material,...)?

[This](https://www.acxesspring.com/spring-diameter-change.html) site gives (for compression of a helical coil) the grown $D_1 = \sqrt{D_m^2 + ((p^2– d^2)\overπ^2}) + d – D_o$

```
Dm = Mean Diameter
p = Pitch
d = Wire Diameter
D = Outer Diameter
π = Pi (3.14)
D0 = Outer Diameter before spring compression
```

but it does not cite a source, nor tell whether this holds for any crosssection, or expanding the spring, as well as leaving out any reference to the extension itself (possibly they look at the case of compression until the wires touch? )

Comment: Hint: try imagining the coil unwrapped into a straight sloped line, where the rise is the original spring length plus the extension.

Comment: @Chemomechanics - for the spring being essentially a line-wire, and the ends of the wire keeping their position on the circumference, this essentially becomes a geometry problem, you are right. One-turn-spring: The cylinder unwraps to a rectangle, the diagonal being the length of the wire. Extending or compressing the spring essentially means having a higher or lower rectangle, retaining length of diagonal. Width of the rectangle divided by pi is the new cylinder diameter. -- but how do material and cross section play into this?

Comment: The spring can't intersect itself, so the rectangle has to have a minimum height that depends on the wire radius and number of turns. As the spring extends at constant wire length, the width of the rectangle must decrease. This corresponds to the reduction in helical coil diameter, yes?

Answer (score 1):

We have the same average wire length before and after the compressive force on spring in pure torsion.

So always from the development of the spring total coil length $L$ is constant. The relation between mean dia/height is a semi-circle.
Neglecting wire diameter $d$,

$$ L^2 = (np)^2+  \pi D_{mean}^2 =   h^2+ \pi D_{mean}^2 \; ; $$

Number of turns $n$ can be non-integer so that the last turn is fractional.

[image]

The relation in the given reference can be arrived at by including the effect of wire diameter $D_{o}=D_{mean}+2d$.